# Microsoft PowerApps referencing Lookup values

Tags: canvas, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps

I am trying to create a canvas app with PowerApps from Microsoft Dynamics 365. I am also trying to set a lookup field value from another lookup field's value and I can't find how to.

1. I have the "User" lookup on my main screen:

[image]

2. I have the Operator value in another screen

[image]

I want to set the "Operator" value from the "User" field. While trying to set the value I found I need a Record instead a single value, so I found on Microsoft's function reference a function to retrieve this record like:

```
Lookup(Operadores, Operador = Operador) // or Operador.Operador
```

But this is not working... so the question I think is simple. How to modify a lookup field with the value of another lookup field in a PowerApps canvas app.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out while trying with a label in the same screen. It is easier than it looked at first.

I used `Set(Operador, Operador.Selected)` in the first screen to set `Operador` as a global variable and then, just set the **DataCardValueN** default selected items to that variable `Operador` and everything works.